# Windows Server 2016 docker image default username/password

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

Is there a default user/password that the base microsoft/windowsservercore image uses?

Comment: have you tried "Administrator" with no password?  according to [this piece of code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/master/windows-container-samples/windowsservercore/MineCraft/MinecraftHost.ps1#L3), looks like you may have to create one via a ps1 script?

Comment: If you just want to connect to the container, use `docker exec -it <container> powershell` and you'll have a PS prompt without having to log in.

Comment: Im not trying to login, just trying to see if there is a default. Tried Admin/nopassword doesnt seem to work as you cannot create a pscredential with emtry string

Comment: Trying Administrator and empty creds when creating service:
The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified
New-Service : Service 'COMPANY Service (COMPANY Service)' cannot be created due to the following
error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified

Comment: Managed to get username...
[Environment]::Username
ContainerAdministrator
empty password gave same error...

Comment: Wondering same. Am trying to start a background process in new ps session. Maybe I need to throw down a new user and then start as that user?

Comment: It looks like documentation is still not clear, but if you drill down into the issues, it says ContainerAdministrator is not actually a user, but a special service account. AD domain users aren't loaded, so you're limited to locally created accounts? You can use the service account to make new users, but I haven't verified yet if you can run standard things as those users in a detached session. I'll investigate. See github issues  https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28585 and  https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28027

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem when i used microsoft/iis image. You are able to connect trough IIS Manager, but you are forced to enter a password because "empty" is not valid.
so what i did with both docker images was the following: i added an admin user

```
RUN NET USER testing "Password01!" /ADD
RUN NET LOCALGROUP "Administrators" "testing" /ADD
```

hope that helps you, using this method for many docker images

Answer (score 2):

You can login into running container with `Enter-PSSession with -RunAsAdministrator` command and then create user and add to administrator's group via `get-command -module Microsoft.Powershell.localaccounts`
I put it in start up script of container and read those off values passed as environment variables which are used to start a container. This way you don't need to hardcode those values into image.